# Restore Btrfs snapshot from subdirectory to parent

Tags: linux, btrfs, snapshot

I have a Btrfs partition which has a single subvolume at the top level (`/root`). It has `subvol=root` option in /etc/fstab.

Every week, I take a readonly snapshot into `/root/snapshots/...` using:

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot -r / /snapshots/"$(date --rfc-3339=date)"
```

(paths don't have `/root` because it's mounted as `subvol=root`).

Now let's say something went wrong and I wanted to restore my root subvolume from a snapshot, I boot from a USB disk and mount the partition as `/mnt/disk` without `subvol=root`. If I try to run:

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot /mnt/disk/root/snapshots/2015-05-01 /mnt/disk/root
```

It creates the new subvolume as `/mnt/disk/root/2015-05-01` instead of replacing `/mnt/disk/root/`. If I try to delete it first by running

```
btrfs subvolume delete /mnt/disk/root
```

It gives the error message:

```
ERROR: cannot delete '/mnt/disk/root' - Directory not empty
```

Is there a way to do this? Or should I get into the habit of creating snapshots **outside** the subvolume being snapshotted?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is where you went wrong:

> If I try to run:
>
> `btrfs subvolume snapshot /mnt/disk/root/snapshots/2015-05-01 /mnt/disk/root`
>
> It creates the new subvolume as /mnt/disk/root/2015-05-01 instead of
>   replacing /mnt/disk/root/.

`btrfs subvolume snapshot` is used to *create* a snapshot of the first argument, and it place it in the directory given by the second argument. It sounds like you're expecting it to *replace* `/mnt/disk/root` instead.

Before you try to overwrite the `/mnt/disk/root` subvolume, you'll need to move or delete it (for example `mv /mnt/disk/root /mnt/disk/root-backup-during-restore`). Then do:

```
btrfs subvolume snapshot /mnt/disk/root/snapshots/2015-05-01 /mnt/disk/
```

And then:

```
mv /mnt/disk/2015-05-01 /mnt/disk/root
```